# Auto hide rows in HTML table when entire row is empty

Tags: html, html-table

In a HTML table how can I auto hide an entire row if all the cells (columns) within that row are empty?

I presume there is something I can add to the  tag that would do this, but I cannot seem to find a solution anywhere.

Comment: You need Javascript/jquery or CSS? or only HTML? Welcome to SO, Tag your questions properly so you can find solution that matches your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, you can use the `hidden` attribute, as in `<tr hidden>`, but this is an HTML5 novelty and has limited browser support. But if you can directly change the HTML markup, the best way to hide an element is to remove it.

Assuming you want something that still lets you have the row there in the markup, for some reason, then you can use JavaScript e.g. as follows:

```
<script>
function emptyCellsOnly(row) {
  var cells =  row.cells;
  for(var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
    if(cells[j].innerHTML !== '') {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  if(emptyCellsOnly(rows[i])) {
    rows[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>
```

The test `if(cells[j].innerHTML !== '')` checks whether cell is *completely* empty, as in `<td></td>`. A space character, or a line break, is not counted as empty. If they should be, modify the condition as needed.

The code `rows[i].style.display = 'none'` hides the row by setting its `display` property to `none`, so CSS-enabled browsers will show the page as if the element were not there, but it is still accessible to scripts, etc. You could alternative remove the element completely from the DOM.

Comment: +1, though I wonder how long it's going to take for us to stop saying "HTML5 has limited browser support", and start saying "Obsolete browsers didn't support HTML5"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript like this

```
$('tr').each(function() {
  if($(this).find('td').length == 0) {
   $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: This hides rows containing no cells (and such rows aren’t very visible anyway).

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found this sollution, which has the advantage over `empty-cells:hide`, that it completely removes the space an empty cell would take up.

```
<style type="text/css">
    table {
        border-spacing: 0px; // removes spaces between empty cells
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    tr, td {
        border-style: none; // see note below
        padding: 0px; // removes spaces between empty cells
        line-height: 2em; // give the text some space inside its cell
        height: 0px; // set the size of empty cells to 0
    }
</style>
```

Unfortunately you have to set `border-style: none;`, else the borders of empty cells will be painted anyway (which results in thick lines).

I tried additional code like:

```
td:empty {
    display: none;
    border-style: none;
}
```

But in my table of 2 columns it removes the borders of either the left or the right column, but never of both...

Any hint at how to remove the borders of empty rows would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in my case cells have Spaces tabs . they are not data.

`areAllCellsEmpty` : true if, all cells.textContent are empty or Whitespace

innerHTML didnt give the result i wanted.

usage:

```
hideEmptyRows_ofTableById("myTable_id");  /* <- your table id here */
```

code:

```
function isEmptyOrSpaces(str){
    return str === null || str.trim() === '' ;
}

function areAllCellsEmpty(row) {
  var cells =  row.cells;
  var anyCellFull = false;
  for(var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
    if( ! isEmptyOrSpaces(cells[j].textContent) ) {
      anyCellFull =true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return !anyCellFull;
}

function hideEmptyRows_ofTableById(elem_id){
  var table = document.getElementById(elem_id);  
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

  for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if( areAllCellsEmpty(rows[i]) ) {
      rows[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```